# Android application isn't getting Push Notification from server

Tags: java, php, android, google-cloud-messaging

my problem is the following:

I want to use Google’s Cloud Messaging server to send a push notification to a user, when he got challenged.

Challenging means, that another user writes an ID into a text field and presses a button. If he presses the button, the app saves the Challenger ID and Challengee ID into a hashma. This Hashmap gets sent to a PHP Server. The PHP Server then retrieves the regid from the database that suits the user id. Now, the PHP Script should send a Request. I’m doing it like that:

```
private function _doPushNotification ( ) {
        $url    = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        $data   = array( 'message' => 'Hey!' );
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids'  => array ( "xxx" ),
            'data'              => $data,
        );
        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . $this->_apiKey,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

        // Set request method to POST
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

        // Set custom headers
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        // Get response back as string
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

        // Set post data
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

        // Send the request
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        // Debug GCM response
        return $result;
    }
```

Now, in my logcat, I’m getting the following output, so it seems to work, but my mobile phone isn’t getting a Push Notification. It seems like the PHP part is correct, right?

This is the logcat output

```
02-11 14:23:24.175: I/System.out(17862):  {"multicast_id":xxx,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1392125005286495%39c58895f9fd7ecd"}]}[done]
02-11 14:23:24.300: I/INTENT(17862): Working... 1/5 @ xxx
02-11 14:23:29.300: I/INTENT(17862): Working... 2/5 @ xxx
02-11 14:23:34.300: I/INTENT(17862): Working... 3/5 @ xxx
02-11 14:23:39.305: I/INTENT(17862): Working... 4/5 @ xxx
02-11 14:23:44.300: I/INTENT(17862): Working... 5/5 @ xxx
02-11 14:23:49.305: I/INTENT(17862): Completed work @ xxx
02-11 14:23:49.365: I/INTENT(17862): Received: Bundle[{from=xxx, message=Hey!, android.support.content.wakelockid=1, collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]
```

So let’s check the Java/Android part for failures. I’ve added these parts to my android manifest as a child of the manifest tag

```
<uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" /> 
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <permission 
        android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

And this as a child of the application tag

```
<receiver
            android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action 
                    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action 
                    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category 
                    android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service 
            android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.GcmIntentService" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I created a GcmBroadcastReceiver and GcmIntentService class and copied the code from the tutorial from Google itself. Also, I’m using the default methods `storeRegistrationId`, `sendRegistrationIdToBackend`, `registerInBackground` `getAppVersion` etc. from Google. Saving them to Shared Preferences and getting them also works. It seems like the only problem I’m currently having, is that the mobile phone isn’t getting the Push Notification. What could be the prboem?
What could be the problem? I don’t know if more code is needed.

Comment: are you getting any errors? Do you know that your service is running (maybe put some log statements in onHandleIntent() in your service)

Comment: Hi, no errors. The Service is running.  Have this as Logging mechanism.

`Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)`

Comment: could you post your notification code (Android part)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by notification code? The GcmBroadcastReceiver and GcmIntentService?

Comment: yes, GcmIntentService

Comment: I just used the exact same as in the tutorial https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Seems like it works now. Since I've changed some settings in the developer console I also had to renew my database entry about the regid. That was the problem... Just resetted all save data and now it works!